# How to make a list of tuples or dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, tuples

I have a little experience with python programming, but just started a job where R is on every computer and I need to use it for at least a little while until my request for python works through the system. I'm trying to write a section of code to iterate through a category and items in that category.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
`my_list <- list(('fruit', ('apple', 'banana', 'orange')), ('vegetables', ('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage')))
                
                
for (category in my_list) {
  print(category[1])
  for (item in category[2]) {
    print(item)
  }
}`
```

My result was:
Error in my_list : object 'my_list' not found

I was wanting it to print the category (fruit and vegetable) followed by the items in that category.

Other than having a hard time finding a simple answer for creating a list of tuples (I think I worked out dictionaries don't exist in R), I'm really confused why the program isn't finding my_list.

For reference, the equivalent python code would be:
a)

```
`my_dict = {'fruit': ('apple', 'banana', 'orange'),
           'vegetables': ('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage')}

for k in my_dict:
    print(k)
    
    for item in my_dict[k]:
        print item
`
```

or
b)

```
`my_list = [('fruit', ('apple', 'banana', 'orange')),
           ('vegetables', ('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage'))]


for category in my_list:
    print(category[0])
    
    for item in category[1]:
        print(item)`
```

Comment: You're `my_list` has a syntax error. R doesn't use `()` for tuple literals. It uses the function `c()` to create vectors. And vectors can't be nested, but lists can. So you want something like `my_list <- list(list('fruit', c('apple', 'banana', 'orange')), list('vegetables', c('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage')))` or maybe just a named list: `my_list <- list(fruit=c('apple', 'banana', 'orange'), vegetables= c('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage'))`

Comment: I'm running through it now. At first try this works, but the snippet is part of a bigger program. I appreciate the help.

I don't know if this is outside the scope here, but if there's an error in creating my_list, why wasn't an error thrown? The program kept going until it got to the loop.

Comment: I don't know why you didn't get an error. If I copy your `my_list <-` and paste it into R i get an error that says `Error: unexpected ',' in "my_list <- list(('fruit',"`. How exactly are you running this code? Maybe you just didn't see the error earlier error. R doesn't necessarily stop running at the first error.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to define `my_list` as a named list of character vectors like this and we will use this definition.  (At the end we shown how to transform to this form.)

```
my_list <- list(
 fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange'),
 vegetables = c('carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage')
)
```

in which case this code works:

```
for(category in names(my_list)) {
  cat(category, "\n")
  for(item in my_list[[category]])
    cat("-", item, "\n")
}
## fruit 
## - apple 
## - banana 
## - orange 
## vegetables 
## - carrot 
## - leek 
## - cabbage
```

In fact depending on what you want it may be sufficient to simply print it using `print(my_list)` or if you are typing it into the R console just like this:

```
my_list
## $fruit
## [1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"
##
## $vegetables
## [1] "carrot"  "leek"    "cabbage"
```

If you already have `my_list2` below it can be transformed to a list `my_list3` which is identical to `my_list` at the top of this answer.

```
my_list2 <- list(
  c('fruit', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange'), 
  c('vegetables', 'carrot', 'leek', 'cabbage')
)

my_list3 <- lapply(my_list2, "[", -1)
names(my_list3) <- sapply(my_list2, "[[", 1)

identical(my_list, my_list3)
## [1] TRUE
```